# How to solve error : [vuex] unknown action type: (method)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

I am trying to display data with `vuex` from api using store (vuex)

so this is my **store.js** file :

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import countries from './module/countries'

const store = createStore({
  modules: {
    countries
  }
});

export default store;
```

**countries.js** file

```
import axios from "axios";

const state = {
  countries:  []
};
const getters = {
  getCountries: () => {
    return state.countries;
  }
};
const mutations = {
  setCountries(state, countries) {
    state.countries = countries;
  }
};
const actions = {
  getCountries ({ commit }) {
    axios.get("https://localhost:44391/api/Pho/GetCountries").then(response => {
       commit('setCountries', response.data);
    })
  }
};
export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  getters,
  mutations,
  actions
};
```

and this is my component

```
 methods: {
   getCountries() {
      this.$store.dispatch('getCountries');
   },
```

When i run the application i got this error `[vuex] unknown action type: getCountries`

Answer (score 3):

You are using `namespaced` modules, so try like:

```
this.$store.dispatch('countries/getCountries');
```

and call your geter like:

```
computed: {
  getData() {
    return this.$store.getters['countries/getCountries']
  }
}
```

Comment: now there is no error but the method does not even launch

Comment: @Nesrine Missaoui hey mate, set console.log in your axios call to see if the action is triggered

Comment: i didn't get anything! no error no data

Comment: `axios.get("https://localhost:44391/api/Pho/GetCountries").then(response => {
        console.log('called') commit('setCountries', response.data);
    })` like this?

Comment: i got the message called but didnt get my data

Comment: ok , so that was the solution for your first problem :) and how do you call your getter? try to console.log(response.data)

Comment: yes i got the data in  console .. i posted the getters and mutations in the question! what should be the problem  there?

Comment: the action is lauched :D but i think there is a prolem lef in the component

Comment: i lost the data again

Answer (score 0):

Store.js

```
import countries from "./modules/countries "

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({     
    modules : {
        countries
    }
});
```